# “Starting from one point” is a correct usage?

Tags: phrase-usage

If I am traveling from one location to another then is it appropriate to say

> I am **starting from** the airport and will reach home in 15 min.

Is “starting from somewhere” a correct usage?

When I am about to start from-let’s say-my house. And I call my boss and say... ”hey, I am **starting from** my house right now.” how does that sound? I mean is this the correct usage? Or "start" is being used only in case of things such as, starting a machine, or starting an engine or starting a work etc?

Comment: Substitute in "coming" for "starting" and you'll be fine.

Comment: One can start *at* or start *from* a place. See [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=start+at%2Cstart+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstart%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstart%20from%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1):

Well, usually "**[start from](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/start+from)**" or "**[start off from](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/start+off+from+some+place)**" is used for journeys, expeditions, tours, trips or voyages.

- We started from New York and flew to France then we took a train to Germany and later went to Poland by car.

Of course you can use "**start *(off)* from**" for simple travelling *(especially if you render it as a trip)*:

- I have started (my trip) from the airport and will reach home in 15 min.

Answer (score 0):

When you use *start* like this, it implies you aren't doing the thing you're talking about yet.

> I am starting from the airport and will reach home in 15 min.

Here, you are talking about travel.  The above sentence seems like it's saying your entire trip began at the airport.  This can sound strange because the airport is a "hop" in your journey, not the real beginning of it.

If you just want to say how much time it will take you to move from point A to B, this is much more idiomatic:

> I'm at the airport and will reach home in 15 min.

Also ...

> And I call my boss and say... ”hey, I am starting from my house right now.” how does that sound?

*Starting* is used for a trip - travel that may take several hours or days, and something you don't do routinely.

You probably want to communicate to your boss that you're already on the way, so you can say this:

> I'm leaving my house now.

This tells your boss that you are actively working on getting out of your house, and also that you are at your house.